# Are there any common phrases that use даваться?

Tags: значения, phrase

The word даваться is translated in my flash card app as "to let oneself".
I was wondering if someone could provide some examples of how to use this word. Are there any stable phrases using даваться, such as "let yourself go" in English?

Comment: I am not going to give myself up. = Не дамся.

Comment: @Avtokod Строго говоря, "не дамся" - это форма глагола "даться", а не "даваться".

Comment: @user4419802 , какой-то странный Вы глагол указали, "даться", у него нет морфологической формы настоящего времени.

Comment: @Avtokod А что странного? Это же глагол совершенного вида.

Comment: @user4419802 , а если нужно настоящее время, то где его форму берете? А если нужно будущее время у глагола "даваться"?

Answer (score 4):

I believe your flash card app means something like this:

> Она в глаза глядит из-под воды, не даётся. // *[А. Н. Толстой. На рыбной ловле (1923)]*

which means

> She (mermaid) looked him in the eye from underwater, but would not let herself be caught.

This is not the main meaning, though. More common meanings would be:

1. A reflexive form of *давать*, used in passive voice: *Школьникам даётся задание* // A task is assigned to the students
2. "To come naturally, easily". *Математика мне не даётся* // Math does not come naturally to me

Answer (score 2):

There is another phrase "Это дается с трудом" "Не даваться легко" - "It is achieved by hard work" "it's not easy to achieve "